# Как автоматически открывать файл через определенный промежуток?

Tags: php

Есть php файл, который парсит данные и создает xml файл. Чтобы спарсить и создать xml файл - нужно его открыть. Поэтому возможно ли в самом php файле или где-нибудь еще настроить автоматическое открытие этого файла через каждый час?

Answer (score 2):

[CRON](http://masterhost.ru/support/doc/cron/)?

> Cron — запуск программ пользователя в указанное время.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку